# Проверка завершена или прошла аудит?

Tags: поддержка, очередь-проверок

Имеем две проверки первых сообщений: [раз](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/review/first-posts/113977), [два](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/review/first-posts/113979).

В одной из них указано:

> Проверка завершена

В другой:

> Проверка прошла аудит

В чем разница?

Answer (score 2):

Разница в том, кого проверяют.

В первом случае вы проверяли первое сообщение новичка.

Во втором случае система проверяла вас, подсунув вам заведомо корректное сообщение. Это и называется аудит.

Comment: Так аудит прошел я, а не проверка, получается.

Comment: @alexolut почему-то был уверен что корявость данного сообщения уже обсуждалась - но не могу найти где

Comment: Наверное потому что обсуждение не прошло аудит и было удалено :)